# In what ways does Backbone.js not support composed views?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I'm referring to this article here

http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/

In my current application I have two views.  The first is the overall view which renders a table.  The second view renders an individual row and is used by the main view.  My row view could be separated into a separate file and used in any other component.  In what way is this not composable?  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the terminology used in the article.

Comment: I am trying to decide whether to use backbone.js (or some alternatives). Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author of that article is specifically referring to composable view templates, like Handlebars, in combination with the backbone view object.

He is essentially wanting to take a view-first approach to composition, where a template would define which views are composed in to the final view. This composition would also determine which objects are used to run the view.

For example, in EmberJS, you can configure a view template to be associated with a specific controller. Doing this, you can compose views in the template itself and the correct controller will be used. This is not possible with Backbone, even when using Handlebars - at least, not without some heavy customization. Backbone takes a "presenter-first" approach (to use the old Model-View-Presenter language) or a View-object first approach, where the view object itself controls which template is rendered.

Comment: Thanks Derick off the top of your head can you think of any applications where view-first is the more natural approach?  Or perhaps to rephrase are there any types of applications where Backbone just won't cut it?  I have read many posts on your blog it's a fantastic resource

Comment: i don't think it matters that much, from a functionality perspective. the end result is HTML that the user sees, and JavaScript that responds to user interaction with HTML. whether it's a template-first approach or a view-object-first approach is more of a tooling detail than anything. ember vs backbone, for example, is mostly personal preference and style